# Writing if-else loop for a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `A`. I want to generate a new list `Anew` with `if-else` loop  such that an  average is taken whenever there are two values. For example, `A[2][0][0]`and `A[2][1][0]` exist hence, average is taken, `A[3][1][0]` doesn't exist and no average is possible for this position in `Anew`.

```
A=[[[0.369577823]],
 [[0.987884443]],
 [[1.244425627], [1.058887146]],
 [[3.707809378]],
 [[0.476881021]],
 [[0.304499065], [1.037728999]],
 [[3.073758392], [5.032947535]]]

Anew=[[[A[0][0][0]],
     [A[1][0][0]],
     [(A[2][0][0]+A[2][1][0])/2],
     [A[3][0][0]],
     [A[4][0][0]],
     [(A[5][0][0]+A[5][1][0])/2],
     [(A[6][0][0]+A[6][1][0])/2]]]
```

The desired output is

```
[[[0.369577823],
  [0.987884443],
  [1.1516563865],
  [3.707809378],
  [0.476881021],
  [0.671114032],
  [4.0533529635]]]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: are the 3 nesting levels really necessary? It appears as if 2 would also work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_numbers=[[[0.369577823]],
 [[0.987884443]],
 [[1.244425627], [1.058887146]],
 [[3.707809378]],
 [[0.476881021]],
 [[0.304499065], [1.037728999]],
 [[3.073758392], [5.032947535]]]
     
new_numbers = [[]]

for numbers in all_numbers:
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        new_numbers[0].append(numbers[0])
    else:
        new_add = 0
        for number in numbers:
            new_add += number[0]
        new_add = new_add/len(numbers)
        new_numbers[0].append([new_add])

print(new_numbers)
```

output

```
[[[0.369577823], [0.987884443], [1.1516563865], [3.707809378], [0.476881021], [0.671114032], [4.0533529635]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```py
A=[[[0.369577823]], [[0.987884443]], [[1.244425627], [1.058887146]], [[3.707809378]], [[0.476881021]], [[0.304499065], [1.037728999]],
 [[3.073758392], [5.032947535]]]

s2 = [[]]

for a in A:
    s = []
    for i in a:
        s.append(sum(i))
    s2[0].append([sum(s)/len(s)])

print(s2)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[[[0.369577823], [0.987884443], [1.1516563865], [3.707809378], [0.476881021], [0.671114032], [4.0533529635]]]
```